# Why is 2D array accessor [Column][Row] and not [Row][Column] format?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

This might be a dumb question but I spend too long not knowing reason.

All through out math classes we learn to put co-ordinates in *(x, y)* fashion. And it sticks into our minds. Now enter C/C++ and to access x=0, y=3 element, I have to do `data[0][3]` instead of `data[3][0]`.

Why array accessing is *(y, x)* format and not *(x, y)*?

Is there particular reason for this or is it something that I just have to accept and move on with my life?

**Edit:**
I was watching this GDC talk by Mike Acton, (http://gdcvault.com/play/1021866/Code-Clinic-2015-How-to) where he talks about performance regarding row major access and column major access. Its understandable since any Array is sequential memory, its takes time to jump to different memory location if i'm trying to do column major access.

Comment: But it is in the row column format...

Comment: It is just what happens when you store your arrays in row-major order. There have been very good reasons to do this in the past, eg. showing an image on a raster display. There's nothing to stop to putting your own arrays in column-major order if that's what you felt you really needed.

Comment: `int array[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` => `array[y][x]`, `int array[WIDTH][HEIGHT]` => `array[x][y]`

Comment: I'm actually curious what made you think that you *have* to do that? E.g.: what resources gave this (mis)information?

Comment: I'm saw this GDC talk

http://gdcvault.com/play/1021866/Code-Clinic-2015-How-to

where author talks about difference between RowMajor access and ColumnMajor access. I know I can store it any format i want, But he shows that RowMajor access is far faster than column major access because there are fewer jumps while reading memory

Comment: Ok, so if you understand why he did it and you know that you can do either, then what exactly is unclear?

Comment: What is unclear is why is do i have to pass index in (y, x) fashion than traditional (x, y) fashion that we are so used to in math.

Comment: ...because you've made your array in row-major order, instead of column-major order. If you wanted the traditional way, make a column-major array. Or, alternatively, make a class that wraps your array and provides a convenience `(x, y)` accessor (which is what most people, and libraries, do in the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [row][col] convention makes since when you look at the conventions used mathematics. Think about and order pair from algebra: (x, y) where the x comes first. This is consistent in math until you get all the way to linear algebra where the order suddenly changes. When dealing with matrices the up-down element should come first as in: M[row][col]. This convention is used in linear algebra for constancy in higher level operations like matrix multiplication...or multiplying a 3x3 matrix by a 3 vector (or 3x1 matrix). If you think of it like a matrix of discrete values instead of a point it makes since.